# What would this program output if it C++ had a dynamic scope?

Tags: c++, dynamic, scope, static

This is a simple program to test static and dynamic scope. However, I can't output the answer using a dynamic scope because C++ uses a static scope.

Definitions:

Static scope - The scope of a variable is based on spatial (block structure) relationship of subprograms (functions)

Dynamic scope - The scope of a variable is based on the calling sequence of subprograms (functions), not on the block structure.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a;
int b;

int p()
{
    int a, p;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    p = 2;
    return p;
}

void print()
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}

void q()
{
    int b;
    a = 3;
    b = 4;
    print();
}

int main()
{
    a = p();
    q();
}
```

This code outputs:

```
3
1
```

using a static scope, but what would it output with a dynamic scope instead?

My guess is

```
3
4
```

but I'm not sure as I have no way to test C++ code using a dynamic scope

Second question: Is there an accessible way to test code examples like this using dynamic scope instead of static for learning purposes?

Comment: What are _static scope_ and _dynamic scope_?

Comment: Since C++ doesn't have 'dynamic scope' and you've not defined what you mean by 'dynamic scope', how do you expect anyone to guess what the answer might be?

Comment: For learning purposes, you'll need to find a language with C-like syntax and dynamic scope.  It won't be called "C++".

Comment: Yes, do you have any recommendations of a language like that? @BenVoigt

Comment: @ayelbee Like this: https://ideone.com/Makxw7? For comparison, the lexical version: https://ideone.com/bRMEVC